Problem in Winforms .NET Core designer and Windows DPI
I get a new computer with high resolution screen, but it causes a problem for me with my old projects. I already have a Windows application I built it with .NET Core, and when I transferred my code to the new PC with Windows 11, I faced a problem that

Scaling on your main display is set to 250%

After instructions, I put these two lines in the main configuration file, as shown in this screenshot:

It is working, but at design time only, and at runtime, the problem is still present, as shown here:

How can I fix this problem? And if I did, will it affect my release versions on the client's PC's in the future?
Can anyone please help me?

What controls and/or code are used to display the images?

Dud you see the notice about being open in DPI unaware mode? Did you click the Learn More link?

yes I make flow the instructions and it's working in the run time only

If you want to keep the application DPI Unaware, just replace SystemAware with DpiUnaware in the .csproj file. It's not exactly clear, though, what you actually want your app to be, in relation to DpiAwareness. <ForceDesignerDpiUnaware> is usually set when migrating a .NET Framework app to .NET, because you plan on fixing the UI after other potential issues have been fixed. The UI needs fixing (refactoring / redesigning) if you want the app to be DpiAware, no way around it

Thank you mr. @Jimi it's working now :)

Good day, I'm glad you've found a way to solve this problem . If possible, please post an answer so that others who encounter similar issues can see the solution.
